# PostgreSQL storage options

Tags: postgresql, database-administration

Does PostgreSQL 9.6 have direct storage facilities like Oracle or Microsoft SQL Server to deal with:

1. read-only storage?
2. compressed storage?
3. limited storage?
4. planned capacity storage?
5. verifying physical data integrity? (eg : values for datatypes)
6. verifying logical data integrity? (constraints)

Thanks

Comment: Did you check the [PostgreSQL 9.6.1 Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/index.html)? You have to do some research by yourself.

Comment: Off course I do, but theese points are not clear to me, otherwise I won't post the question. For instance they talk about TOAST which does some compression... And I want to know if there is some add-on that can do it !

Answer (score 0):

re 1) no

re 2) Postgres compresses data automatically, but can also store its database files on a file system that compresses (e.g. btrf, zfs, NTFS)

re 5) To verify physical integrety, you can turn on checksums on data pages during initdb. Not sure what you mean with "values for datatypes" but Postgres won't let you store invalid values for a datatype (e.g. February 31st in a `date` column).

re 6) that's what constraints are for

no idea what 3 and 4 are supposed to mean.

Comment: 3) to say to the database, you have only 10 Gb on that storage (tablespace)
4) to say, reserve me a 50 Gb on that storage (tablespace)
When you says automaticallay compresses data, which compression algorithm is in use ?